# Swift ios : Implement scroll on Bar chart

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

Tried to implement scroll on Barchart using scale x to 2 for zoom in. But the issue is the x-axis values are not center-aligned with Bar chart.
Labels count is based on day and month values.

```
barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(labels.count - 1)

barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(Double(labels.count)/2)
or 
barChartView.zoom(scaleX: 2, scaleY: 0, x: 0, y: 0)
```

for scroll implemented like,

```
barChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(Int(Double(labels.count)/2), force: true)
```

Please suggest to us the correct approach to avoid miss align of x-axis values with the bar chart.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, I assume your expected behaviour is that the chart

- shows at most half of all available bars
- allows the user to zoom indefinitly (minimum = 0)
- allows the user to scroll (left/right)

If this is the case, you would apply the following code:

```
barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(labels.count - 1)

barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(Double(labels.count)/2)
barChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(Int(Double(labels.count)/2), force: false)
```

`.zoom`should be avoided since it sets multiple unwanted values (`scaleY`, `x`, `y`) and hence adds unwanted features when scrolling.

It is important to set the `force` flag to `false`. This is the parameter that caused your miss alignment as described in the documentation:

https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/

> setLabelCount(int count, boolean force): Sets the number of labels for the y-axis. Be aware that this number is not fixed (if force == false) and can only be approximated. If force is enabled (true), then the exact specified label-count is drawn – this can lead to uneven numbers on the axis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine with set force to false. :)

Answer (score 0):

To make the chart horizontal scroll and adjust the bars and y-axis labels properly:

```
let visibleXRange = 6 // Number of values to show in y-Axis
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(xAxisValues.count)
barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(Double(visibleXRange))
barChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(visibleXRange, force: false)
barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
barChartView.xAxis.labelCount = visibleXRange
```

Make sure the `dragEnabled = true`